# Pandas Crosstab table with Ordered Categorical Variables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matrix, pivot-table

I'm facing the same issue as this guy:
[Pandas Crosstab table with Unordered Categorical Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339092/pandas-crosstab-table-with-unordered-categorical-variables)

But I managed to get the first part, now I have another doubt
I also have a Pokémon DF which I'm playing with and trying to do a co-occurrence matrix. As responded there, I managed to sort the Types properly but the results of the matrix is 'one-sided'.

```
df.head(10)

         name    type1    type2
   Abomasnow    Grass      Ice
        Abra  Psychic  Psychic
       Absol     Dark     Dark
    Accelgor      Bug      Bug
   Aegislash    Steel    Ghost
  Aerodactyl     Rock   Flying
      Aggron    Steel     Rock
       Aipom   Normal   Normal
    Alakazam  Psychic  Psychic
    Alcremie    Fairy    Fairy



Sorted all
cols = ['type1', 'type2']
types_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols], axis=1), columns=cols) #Sorted the types as Answered in the previous Question link
matrix_df = pd.crosstab(types_df['type1'], types_df['type2'], dropna=False) #Created the co-occurrence matrix

Matrix result:

type2   Bug Dark Dragon Electric Fairy Fighting Fire Flying Ghost Grass Ground Ice Normal Poison Psychic Rock Steel Water
type1                                                                       
Bug     23  1   0   4   2   4   4   13  1   6   1   2   0   12  3   6   5   5
Dark    0   13  5   1   3   4   4   7   2   7   4   3   1   4   2   1   3   4
Dragon  0   0   13  3   0   3   2   6   4   3   6   4   2   3   2   2   2   5
Electric0   0   0   35  2   3   0   5   1   0   2   1   2   2   0   1   4   2
Fairy   0   0   0   0   21  1   0   3   2   5   0   0   4   0   8   2   6   4
Fighting0   0   0   0   0   28  6   2   2   3   1   1   2   3   3   1   2   3
Fire    0   0   0   0   0   0   36  6   6   1   2   0   2   3   3   3   1   1
Flying  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   2   6   3   2   27  3   6   4   3   8
Ghost   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  8   5   1   0   3   2   0   4   3
Grass   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   46  3   2   5   14  5   2   3   3
Ground  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  3   2   3   2   9   3   9
Ice     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   3   2   0   8
Normal  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   74  2   6   0   0   1
Poison  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   3   2   6
Psychic 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   39  2   7   6
Rock    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  7   11
Steel   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  1
Water   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   74
```

I know is kind messy to see, but the 'upper right' side has the occurrences, now I want it to 'mirror' on the 'left down' side. As something like:

```
type Bug Dark Dragon Electric Fairy Fighting Fire Flying Ghost Grass Ground Ice Normal Poison Psychic Rock Steel Water
Bug    23   1   0   4   2   4   4   13  1   6   1   2   0   12  3   6   5   5
Dark    1   13  5   1   3   4   4   7   2   7   4   3   1   4   2   1   3   4
Dragon  0   5   13  3   0   3   2   6   4   3   6   4   2   3   2   2   2   5
Electric4   1   3   35  2   3   0   5   1   0   2   1   2   2   0   1   4   2
Fairy   2   3   0   2   21  1   0   3   2   5   0   0   4   0   8   2   6   4
Fighting4   4   3   3   1   28  6   2   2   3   1   1   2   3   3   1   2   3
Fire    4   4   2   0   0   6   36  6   6   1   2   0   2   3   3   3   1   1
Flying  13  7   6   5   3   2   6   3   2   6   3   2   27  3   6   4   3   8
Ghost   1   2   4   1   2   2   6   2   16  8   5   1   0   3   2   0   4   3
Grass   6   7   3   0   5   3   1   6   8   46  3   2   5   14  5   2   3   3
Ground  1   4   6   2   0   1   2   3   5   3   17  3   2   3   2   9   3   9
Ice     2   3   4   1   0   1   0   2   1   2   3   16  0   0   3   2   0   8
Normal  0   1   2   2   4   2   2   27  0   5   2   0   74  2   6   0   0   1
Poison  12  4   3   2   0   3   3   3   3   14  3   0   2   16  0   3   2   6
Psychic 3   2   2   0   8   3   3   6   2   5   2   3   6   0   39  2   7   6
Rock    6   1   2   1   2   1   3   4   0   2   9   2   0   3   2   17  7   11
Steel   5   3   2   4   6   2   1   3   4   3   3   0   0   2   7   7   10  1
Water   5   4   5   2   4   3   1   8   3   3   9   8   1   6   6   11  1   74
```

I tried creating 2 DFs (up & down) so I can merge them somehow like:

```
cols = ['type1', 'type2']
types_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols], axis=1), columns=cols)
up_df = pd.crosstab(types_df['type1'], types_df['type2'], dropna=False)
down_df = pd.crosstab(types_df['type2'], types_df['type1'], dropna=False)

up_df = up_df.reset_index().rename({'type1':'type'}, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1) #Upper Right
down_df = down_df.reset_index().rename({'type2':'type'}, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)  #Downer Left

**up_df.add(down_df) #Almost right but since it sum everything, the Diagonal where summed up**
```

Maybe Dividing by 2 only the diagonal could work

Also tried some pd.merge and pd.concat()

And pd.pivot_table() but I don't know how to properly set this up to accomplish it since is very similar to pd.crosstab()

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444930/copy-upper-triangle-to-lower-triangle-in-a-python-matrix

Comment: Thank you so much, the following worked:
X = np.triu(X)
X = X + X.T - np.diag(np.diag(X))

I cant believe I havent found it while researching it